# MySQL import with single quotes

Tags: mysql, import, dump

im turning my head crazy, since I do have some problems importing a large SQL file to MySQL database.

Basically I get the following error, while the import runs:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Ogni giorno, milioni di piccoli germogli di soia vengono strappati al loro ambi' at line 1
```

It seems like there is some content with a single quote ' in it. This happens the import to break. The big problem is, that my SQL-File is about 16 gigabytes large, as this is a very big database.

Does anyone know, how to solve this problem? Is there any way to escape quotes while importing a file?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the file that you have was escaped to be used on MS Sql Server, where two single quotes `''` escapes a quote `'`.  In order to convert it to mysql you can try to convert every two single quotes to mysql escape notation: backslash and single quote `\'`.
Take in mind that this is only a dirty trick, other not properly escaped sequences may fail.

Comment: Indeed this would be a solution - even when it's not clean. But my file is about 16 GB large. So there is no posibility to open the file and edit it with search and replace.

Comment: write a little program to loop replacing over de text.